# PHPExcel downloaded file giving error as file extension not correct in live server

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel library for downloading excel sheet in CodeIgniter framework. Its working fine in local server, its downloading excel sheet file, opening and showing correct data, now when I run that same code in live server it is downloading, when I open that file, it is giving this error, The file you are trying to open 'filename.xsl' is in a different format than specified by the file extension. verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file.

**Here is the code.**

```
$this->excel->createSheet();
$this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(2);
$filename='Monthly Report'.date("m-d-Y, h:i:s").'.xls';
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

I also used the `method ob_end_clean();` before $objWriter, still got the same error. Any help will be appreciated.[it's in a live server on the local server it's working fine]

Comment: I just found this: http://www.repairmsexcel.com/blog/how-to-fix-excel-error-the-file-you-are-trying-to-open-is-in-different-format-than-specified-by-the-file-extension Which cracked me up to realize there's an entire domain/blog setup dedicated to repairing Excel files XD

Answer (score 0):

ob_end_clean();
ob_start();

Used the above lines of code before $objWriter->save('php://output');
and it worked.